# Exchange 2010 - a domain moved to an external mail host - Exchange is still trying to send the domain locally

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

So we have an exchange 2010 server that hosts email for about 10 domains.
One of those domains has moved to an outside mail provider.  We have removed this domain from the 'accepted domains' list.
However it is still trying to store the emails locally - eg.  anyone that tries to send an email within the Active Directory internal office to this specific domain, Exchange doesn't pass it on but still tries to store the email message locally.
The domain users in the Recipients List have not been removed yet.   - this is for archival purposes. 
From what I understood, just removing the specific domain from 'Accepted Domains' should be enough to have Exchange pass the mail to the proper MX host.

does anything else have to be done to make this work?
These 'internal' users, and users within this domain (email@emailmoved.com) are also on the local Active Directory - just their email is hosted externally now.  Why is exchange still trying to store the emails locally?

Comment: Did the answer from [joeqwerty](https://serverfault.com/users/19152/joeqwerty) solved your issue? Could you accept it in this case so the other users know?

Answer (score 1):

`Why is exchange still trying to store the emails locally?` - Because even though Exchange is no longer authoritative for this domain there are still objects with email addresses for this domain. You need to remove this domain from your email address policy and make sure that the email address for this domain is removed from all objects. Removing it from the email address policy should accomplish this.